# If $f \in C([0, \infty))$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} f(x)\int_0^x f^2(t) \ dt = 1$, then $f(x) \sim \left(\frac{1}{3x}\right)^{1/3}$

Tags: integration, limits, asymptotics, epsilon-delta

Let $f:[0, \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} f(x)\int_0^x f^2(t) \ dt = 1
$$
I want to conclude that
$$f(x) \sim \left(\frac{1}{3x}\right)^{1/3}$$
i.e. $$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(x)}{\left(\frac{1}{3x}\right)^{1/3}} = 1$$

I tried to argue by contradiction, but my attempt was terribly unsuccessful and now seems hopeless:

Suppose that the conclusion is false. Then, for some $\varepsilon > 0$ we have that

$$
\left|\frac{f(x)}{\left(\frac{1}{3x}\right)^{1/3}}-1\right|\ge \varepsilon
$$
for arbitrarily large $x$. Equivalently,
$$
\frac{f(x)}{\left(\frac{1}{3x}\right)^{1/3}} \ge 1 + \varepsilon
$$
<strike>and</strike> OR
$$
\frac{f(x)}{\left(\frac{1}{3x}\right)^{1/3}} \le 1 - \varepsilon
$$

Any ideas to get started would be appreciated.

Comment: Your assumption to seek a contradiction does not make sense because $1-\varepsilon \geq 1+\varepsilon$ cannot hold for any positive $\varepsilon$.

Comment: @Gary Right! I was going for $\left| \frac{f(x)}{(1/3x)^{1/3}} - 1\right| \ge \epsilon$. This is correct though right?

Comment: @Gary I have made an edit. Is the argument valid now?

Comment: Looks like big problems regarding the _meaning_ of "we have that
$
\left|\frac{f(x)}{\left(\frac{1}{3x}\right)^{1/3}}-1\right|\ge \varepsilon
$
for arbitrarily large $x$". What's true is that inequality holds for some arbitrarily large $x$, But integrating the inequality, as you do, is only valid if it holds for _all_ $x$.

Comment: Saying $|l-1|>\epsilon$ is equivalent to "$l>1+\epsilon$ **or** $l<1-\epsilon$", not "and". Makes a big difference.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I am not integrating the inequality though, only multiplying through by $\int_0^x f^2(t) \ dt$, so that $f(x)\int_0^x f^2(t) \ dt \rightarrow 1$ through those arbitrarily large $x$ by hypothesis.

Comment: then later you"deduce" that something happens as $x\to\infty$; in fact the whatever only happens along a _subsequence_. (I don't have the example handy, but it seems pretty clear to me that the result is actually false...)

Comment: I understand now. I'm confusing $|L-1| < \epsilon \iff 1-\epsilon <L<1+\epsilon$ with the $|L-1| > \epsilon$ case.

Comment: one of the formulas says $\frac{f(x)}{\left(\frac{1}{3x}\right)^{1/3}}<\frac{f(x)}{\left(\frac{1}{3x}\right)^{1/3}}$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122445/discussion-between-fwd-and-david-c-ullrich).

Comment: What's to discuss? We've established that the proof you give here is very wrong. We might discuss how to fix it, but I have no idea how to fix it, and suspect it's impossible.

Comment: I apologize. I must have clicked that "automatically move to chat button". I also think this idea won't work now that I've seen the grave errors I committed.

Comment: It's an interesting question. I try to settle such things by looking for a counterexample, then trying to see why I can't find one if I can't. Finding the counterexample is so far harder than I expected...

Comment: Just curious. Is this a part of your approach to solve some other problem or is it some exercise in a text?

Comment: I believe it's an exercise from some text.

Comment: IF $f(x)$ is $C^1$ then things become relativly easy as soon as we can justify exchanging $\frac d{dx} \& \lim$ which should be doable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $g(x) = \int_{0}^{x} f(t)^2\mathrm{dt}$, we have by squaring the condition
on $f$:
$$\lim g^{\prime}(x) g(x)^2 = 1 $$

so for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $A > 0$, s.t.
$$1 - \varepsilon < g'(x)g(x)^2 < 1 + \varepsilon$$
by integrating from $A$ to $x$, we deduce:
$$(1-\varepsilon)x + \frac1{3}g(A)^3 < \frac1{3}g(x)^3 < (1+\varepsilon)x + \frac1{3}g(A)^3$$
so:
$$g(x) \sim \sqrt[3]{3x}$$
From $f(x)g(x) \sim 1$ we deduce:
$$f(x) \sim \frac1{\sqrt[3]{3x}}$$